# is it possible to display background image in css3 stored in php variable?

Tags: php, css

Is it possible to display a background image in css3 stored in a php variable?

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url("$background_img_location");
}
```

Comment: Post code as plain text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in the code of your page...

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url("<?php echo $background_img_location; ?>");
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help. =D

Answer (score 0):

After doing the query, generate the CSS in the PHP script:

```
?>
<style>
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url("<?php echo $background_img_location; ?>");
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the .css file extension, use .php

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.php' />
```

At the top of your new style.php file set the Content-type back to CSS:

```
<?php

   header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

?>
```

Set up variables for whatever you like:

```
<?php

  header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

  $bgImage = 'http://www.somesite.com/bgimage.jpg';

?>
```

Below all that PHP stuff, you can add regular CSS, as well as some PHP to output the variable:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url("<?php echo $bgImage; ?>");
}
```

Final output should look like this:

```
<?php

  header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

  $bgImage = 'http://www.somesite.com/bgimage.jpg';

  //declare more variables here

?>

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: url("<?php echo $bgImage; ?>");
}

/* more css here */
```